# Gnome 3 (Gnome Shell) JavaScript/CSS engine

Tags: javascript, css, gnome, gnome-3, gnome-shell

I am wondering, which type and version of JavaScript/CSS engines is `Gnome 3` aka `Gnome Shell` using?

Is there any information about current version, etc?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

For JavaScript the engine [GJS](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gjs/blob/master/doc/Home.md) (based on SpiderMonkey).  For theming, it is used a sort of superset of [CSS2](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkCssProvider.html#GtkCssProvider.description).  You might be interested in reading the documentation of [GtkCssProvider](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkCssProvider.html) and the [migration information](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/ch25s02.html#gtk-migrating-GtkStyleContext).

On the other hand, there are some CSS3-like operations available, such as radial and linear gradients.  You might want to take a look the article [*Styling GTK+ with CSS*](http://thegnomejournal.wordpress.com/2011/03/15/styling-gtk-with-css/) to get some ideas.  The article was written by the developer who wrote [GtkCssProvider](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkCssProvider.html).

Comment: Note that GNOME Shell uses mx to draw widgets. See more on http://live.gnome.org/GnomeShell/Development

Comment: Updated. Although, it would have been better to say which one :-)

Answer (score 2):

The JavaScript engine is [GJS](http://live.gnome.org/Gjs). The CSS is, I believe, internal - in GTK 3, all theming is done using CSS.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know that CSS is used for theming. However there is no information if it is CSS2/CSS3 or CSS10.